# Why not fire the save_post event?

Tags: save-post

World!

Why not fire the `save_post` event?

```
function action_function_name_13( $content ) {

  $content = '<div>' . $content . '</div>';

  return $content;

}

add_action( 'save_post', 'action_function_name_13' );
```

You need to perform actions with the `$content` variable, that is during the save or update a post.

Sorry, translated by the interpreter...

Answer (score 3):

The `save_post` action hook fires after a post is saved: every time, even for autosaves.

If you look at the reference for [`save_post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/), you'll see that the callback receives three parameters: the first is an integer `$post_ID`, the second is a WP_Post object `$post`, and the third is a `boolean` $update. None of the parameters are a string of the content.

Based upon your code, it appears that you are trying to add a filter to [`the_content`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content/). So your code should be:

```
function action_function_name_13( $content ) {
  return '<div>' . $content . '</div>';
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'action_function_name_13' );
```

If this isn't what you're trying to do, look through the [hook reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/) for a hook that describes what you're trying and update your question.

---

Here's a way to modify the post content *after* it has been saved to the database.

```
//* save_post fires *after* the post has been saved to the database
add_action( 'save_post', 'wpse_266719_save_post', 10, 3 );
function wpse_266719_save_post( $post_ID, $post, $update ) {
  //* Remove action so it doesn't fire on wp_update_post()
  remove_action( 'save_post', 'wpse_266719_save_post', 10 ); 
  $id = $post->ID;
  $content = htmlspecialchars( $post->post_content, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', false );
  $postarr = array( 'ID' => $id, 'post_content' => $content, );
  wp_update_post( $postarr );
}
```